# Запятая или тире при перечислении страниц и рисунков?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, перечисление

См. рис. 5, 8-9 или см. рис. 5, 8, 9;
см. с. 5, 8-9 или см. с. 5, 8, 9.
Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире ставится для обозначения интервалов. Нужно различать:

- 5—6 рисунков (примерное значение, у Розенталя тире и отбивка 5 – 6, а у Мильчина нет: [машин 5—6](http://www.diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/6.html#6.1.4.));
- рис. 5, 6;
- с. 5—6 (два номера подряд показывают как интервал, если материал "перетекает" с одной страницы на другую);
- с. 5—7 (интервал).

Как указано у Мильчина ([6.1.5.    Интервал значений](http://www.diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/6.html#6.1.4.)), тире в качестве знака интервала ставится между числами в цифровой форме и по техн. правилам набора не отбивается от цифр.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет так:
**См. рис. 5, 8, 9; см. с. 5, 8, 9.**

Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами **для обозначения пределов**:

в) количественных числительных, например: рукопись объемом восемь – десять авторских листов (то же цифрами: 8–10); 5–6-кратное превосходство.
В этих случаях тире заменяет по смыслу слова **"от ... до"**.
[**§82. Соединительное тире**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm)

В Вашем перечислении рисунков (и страниц) нет необходимости ставить тире.

*Помимо этого, для формирования правильной реакции опоры, навыков ходьбы рекомендуются упражнения (см.: комплекс М 1, упр. 5, 6 — рис. 5, 6; комплекс М 2, **упр. 5, 8, 9 — рис. 9, 11, 12**; комплекс М 4, **упр. 10, 11, 14 — рис. 16, 17, 20**; комплекс М 5 <...>).*

Comment: При перечислении страниц тире может ставиться. У Мильчина пример на с. 88: "с. 8–9"

Comment: Вашу "отсылку" к Мильчину найти невозможно. Ссылочку не дадите - где и в каком контексте **такую особенность** можно посмотреть?

Comment: (http://www.diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/4.html#4.3.7.):  4.4.4.    Сокращения при внутритекстовых ссылках и сопоставлениях (гл., п., подп., разд., рис., с, см., ср., табл., ч.)

Все сокращения, кроме см. и ср., употребляются только в сочетании с цифрами или буквами; напр.: в гл. 22, в подп. 5а; согласно п. 10; в разд. 1; по данным разд. А; на рис. 8, в табл. 2, с. 8—9.

Answer (score 1):

Если по одному рисунку на каждой странице + текст, то однозначно 5, 8, 9

Если на каждой странице только по одному рисунку без текста, но не более двух подряд, то лучше тоже 5, 8, 9

Если на каждой странице только по одному рисунку без текста, но при этом подряд много страниц, то целесообразно сократить список коротким тире: 5, 8–11

Если на каждой странице несколько рисунков и ссылка подразумевает их все, то однозначно нужно указать интервал, дескать, всё с 8 по 9 страницу подходит.

Исправление: дефис пишется в словах, а этом случае речь о коротком тире, это другой знак.

Comment: По поводу метки "дефис": сейчас подправлю. Тире, конечно! (Торопилася...).